# Can I calibrate to 100% of my sample in ML regression?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, validation, estimators, calibration

I have a standard ML regression model trained on 80% of my data with 20% saved for testing.

I want my model to match my full sample as best possible.

Can I multiply my outputs by *mean(**observations** from 100% of my data) / mean(**predictions** on 100% of my data)*?

(This way my average prediction will match my average observation)

Why not? And what are the mathematical implications?

Comment: If you incorporate your test data into your model, then testing the model against your test data does not a proper view of the performance of your model against unseen data.  Similarly if you do test properly and then decide to go back and change your model: you cannot properly test again. That may be a price you are willing to pay: some people run the test properly, accept the model for use on the basis of those test results, and then retrain the model using all the data, knowing that they cannot retest until they get new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your training and test sets differed substantially in terms of average observations, as your question suggests, then perhaps there is a problem with your train/test split. The problem potentially posed by a difference in average observations between the training and test sets is that the two sets might not represent the same underlying population. That puts many modeling assumptions into question. You certainly don't want your model to depend heavily on a particular single choice of train/test split.

Another approach is to build the model first on the entire data set. You then evaluate the performance of the *modeling method* by repeating all modeling steps on multiple bootstrap samples of the data, using the entire data set as the test set for each model. That provides estimates of optimism bias in the modeling method. Frank Harrell estimates that this approach is superior unless you have [20,000 or more observations](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/). depending on the signal/noise ratio in your data.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
In my problem, the average prediction and average observation only differ by about 2%. 
I'm sure that adjusting my model has deeper implications, but I don't understand what those implications are. Would you be able to explain some of the core reasons why everyone doesn't do this? Or where I can learn about the full impact of calibrating like this?

Comment: @YuGiJoe in the train/test scenario, if you re-adjust your model to include the test set data, you no longer have an independent estimate of how well the _adjusted_ model might work on the underlying population. That defeats the purpose of the train/test split, which is to first develop a model and then see how well it works on an independent sample from the underlying population, without data leakage between the two sets. The approach I describe in the second paragraph uses all the data, but it evaluates the quality of the _modeling process_ more than the model itself.